# Pagination using javascript only

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, pagination

I'm working on a Django project

my code is javascript heavy, I want a way to do pagination with javascript only

first i'm fetching from all_posts url to get all posts data

```
fetch('/all_posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
        display_posts(user, posts)
    })
```

then the method display_posts create a card for each post and append it to `<div id="all_posts">` in index.html

```
function display_posts(userr, postss){
    for (post in postss){
        //create each post_container
        //put data inside it
        document.querySelector('#all_posts').append(post_container)
    }
```

I can't go back to do it with Django loops and pagination in html, I want a way to do it using javascript only

can anyone help me please and provide me with code examples on how to it using any plugin, thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to display in pagination then don't display all from `postss` but only part of them - I don't know if JavaScript has slicing `[start:start+number_of_posts_on_page]` to get only part of posts. And you would need variable with `start` which is changed when you press button with `"Next Page"`.

Comment: what did you try to do? What did you find in Google? As for me you have nothing at this moment and I don't see you tried to resolve this problem on your own. I would expect that you resolve this problem faster using Google then waiting for answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: See this https://codepen.io/davidofug/pen/JjYdExX?editors=0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some variables `start`, `number` to slice posts - ie. `posts.slice(start, start+number)` - and display only these posts.

And buttons `Next Page`, `Prev Page` should change `start` and display again posts from `posts.slice(start, start+number)`

---

Primitive example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div id="all_posts"></div>

<button onclick="prev_page()">Prev Page</button>
<button onclick="next_page()">Next Page</button>

<script>
var posts = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
var start = 0;
var number = 2;

var posts_div = document.querySelector('#all_posts');

function display(posts) {
  
  // remove previous posts
  posts_div.innerHTML = '';
  
  // get only part of posts
  data = posts.slice(start, start+number);

  for(post in data){
    post_container = document.createElement('div');
    post_container.innerHTML = data[post];
    posts_div.append(post_container);
  }
}

function next_page(){
  if(start + number < posts.length){
    start = start + number;
    display(posts);
  }    
}

function prev_page(){
  if(start >= number){
    start = start - number;
    display(posts);
  }
}

// display few posts at start
display(posts);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. I tried using hard solutions like pagination plugins, and forgot about that I can do it easily using the loop, thanks again!!